# $XY^4+YZ^4+XZ^4$ has no singular points

Tags: algebraic-curves, solution-verification

In the question 5.1 in the Fulton's algebraic curves book he asked to find the multiple points of $$F=XY^4+YZ^4+XZ^4$$

Calculating the partial derivatives, we have:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}=Y^4+Z^4=0$

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}= 4XY^3+Z^4=0$

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}=4YZ^3+4XZ^3=0$

I found the point $p=(1:0:0)$ as a multiple point, am I right? I saw a solution to this exercise elsewhere saying that $F$ doesn't have singular points.

If I'm right what's the best method in this case to calculate the multiplicity at this point?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For this curve $[1:0:0]$ is, indeed, a singular point. I might guess that the non-singularity that you saw really about the zeros of the symmetric polynomial
$$XY^4+YZ^4+ZX^4,$$ but that is just speculation. The equation that you gave does appear in Problem 5.2. in my copy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Page 54 of the book (page 62 of the pdf) http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

Comment: So this is just a typo.

Comment: @Cantlog yes, but what's the best method in this case to calculate the multiplicity at this point?

Comment: The basic method is to replace $X$ with $1$, and compute the dimension of the vector space quotient of $k[Y,Z]_{(Y,Z)}$ by the ideal generated by $g(Y,Z):=F(1, Y, Z)$ and the partial derivatives of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

As defined in chapter 5 $m_P(F)=m_P(F_*)$ w.r.t. to $U_1$, which is $F_*=Y^4+Z^4+YZ^4$ and $P=(0,0)$. As defined in chapter 3 the multiplicity is the degree of lowest degree form of $F_*$, which is 4.